# scrollComponentToVisible not working in codenameone on android, with keyboard open

Tags: codenameone

On Android, when using scrollComponentToVisible and the keyboard is open, the component is not scrolled to the actual visible area, but under the keyboard.

Comment: Try using the desktop mode in the simulator and reduce it to the proportions you would see with the keyboard open. Can you reproduce the issue in that situation? If so you can inspect the components and see the size/location of the scrollable container. You can also use a debugger to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by wrapping the code in a "callSerially" statement. I also changed the direct scroll call to a "requestFocus" scroll coupled with a "startAsyncEditing".